# Extend module with global configuration without breaking current usages

Tags: node.js

I want to extend a current Node.js module with some global config setting being configured once without breaking current usages of this module.

This is the signature of the module:

```
const myFunction = function(someOptions) { ... };
module.exports = myFunction;
```

Usage is

```
const myFunction = require('myfunction');
const result = myFunction(options);
```

Now I want to set some options on application startup to be used by the module `myfunction` whenever being `require`d without breaking current usages of the module `myfunction`.

If possible, I want to avoid using Node.js `global`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in JavaScript are just objects, so you can give them properties. This is a *little* hacky, but it could certainly work for you:

```
// greeter.js

function sayHello() {
    const message = sayHello.message || "Hi";
    console.log(message);
}
module.exports = sayHello;
```

You can now set the config of this function globally as follows:

```
const sayHello = require("./greeter.js");
sayHello.message = "S'up dawg";
```

Any subsequent calls to `sayHello()` after the code above is executed will use the overridden message. This works because [calls to `require()` are cached](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require), so each time you `require(./greeter.js);` you're getting back exactly the same function object.